# YII EMongoDocumentDataProvider

Tags: php, mongodb, yii

My collactions-category have 3 fields-  `_id` ,`name`, `parent_id`

`parent_id` is `_id` of parent

In `actionIndex`

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $dataProvider=new EMongoDocumentDataProvider('Category');
    $this->render('index',array(
        'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    ));
}
```

How I can replace `parent_id` by name of parent category

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't provide enough information but I assume you wish to use this with `GGridView`. That is where you will have to do this, within the declaration of the `CGridView`:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    'columns'=>array(
        array(
            'name' => 'Parent',
            'value' => '$data->parent->name'
        )
    )
);
```

`parent` in `$data->parent` is the name of the relation within your model to the parent model.

Comment: I don't have $data->parent->name, I have only parent_id 
I try create relation http://canni.github.io/YiiMongoDbSuite/xhtml/advanced.relations.html

I write in Category model

public function parent_name()
    {
       
        return Category::model()->find(array('name'=>'asd'));
    }

but haven't effect